# Can I travel from the UK to the USA with my tarantula (Grammostola pulcher) - Brazillian Black?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, pets, prohibited-items

Can I travel from the UK to the USA with my tarantula (Grammostola pulcher) - Brazillian Black? I have had her 18 years. I got her when young from a pet shop.

If so who and what do I need to see and do?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you will need to [contact US Fish and Wildlife Services](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/yellowbook/2018/conveyance-transportation-issues/taking-animals-animal-products-across-international-borders) in order to see if your spider is admissible.  There is a good chance that it isn't.

Also, the answer may vary based on whether you are simply visiting the US temporarily, or if you are emigrating there.  (In the latter case, this question better fits our sister site, [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).